# Oracle SQL - Help using Case in a Select Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

```
CREATE TABLE student_totalexp2 nologging compress AS
SELECT /*+parallel(a,4)*/ DISTINCT a.member_sk, 
       CASE 
         WHEN b.end_date IS NULL THEN 
           SYSDATE - MIN(TO_DATE(b.start_date,'yyyymm'))
         ELSE 
           (MAX(TO_DATE(b.end_date,'yyyymm')) - MIN(TO_DATE(b.start_date,'yyyymm')))  
       END as days_experience
  FROM student_schools a 
  JOIN rdorwart.position_rd b ON a.member_sk = b.member_sk 
 WHERE days_experience < 730 
 GROUP BY a.member_sk;

SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM student_experience;
```

Any idea why I keep getting this error: Error report:

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DAYS_EXPERIENCE": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot reference a alias in the `WHERE` clause. Either use a subquery, or better just the entire `CASE...END` into your where clause.

Updated query per OP's comments:

```
create table student_totalexp2 nologging compress as 
SELECT a.member_sk, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN b.end_date IS NULL
    THEN sysdate 
    ELSE to_date(b.end_date,'yyyymm') 
  END - to_date(b.start_date,'yyyymm')) as days_experience
FROM student_schools a INNER JOIN rdorwart.position_rd b 
  ON a.member_sk = b.member_sk 
GROUP BY a.member_sk
HAVING SUM(
  CASE WHEN b.end_date IS NULL
    THEN sysdate 
    ELSE to_date(b.end_date,'yyyymm') 
  END - to_date(b.start_date,'yyyymm')
  ) < 730;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student_experience;
```

Comment: With your code, I get an error that points to the WHERE clause: SQL Error: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"

Comment: @ame Since it uses aggregate functions, it belongs in the `HAVING` clause. Updated my code.

Comment: hmmm... I still get the same error, even with the updated code. SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: @ame The `CASE` includes both single and aggregate fields, If you can please post your table definition, sample data & what you want the results to look like we can better help you!

Comment: The student_schools table has student ids and the position_rd table has jobs (so there are multiple jobs per student id). I want to create a table with 2 fields: field 1 - distinct student id, field 2 - total number of days employed. Then, I'd like to exclude students with over 2 years of work experience (730 days). The end result is a table with student ids who have less than 730 days of experience.

Comment: @ame I Updated the query. Note 1) Removed the `DISTINCT` since you have the `GROUP BY` 2) Simplified the `CASE`.

Comment: now I get the following error: SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER...

Comment: Does the CASE expression in SELECT (non-aggregate) actually work?

Comment: @richard-aka-cyberkiwi No. good point. Updated. Answer was brain compiled with help from Notepad++

Comment: But it was accepted - go figure - so I asked. But I get you now about the gaps. I was literally fixing the OP's query (max against min).

Answer (score 2):

The below is a direct simplification of the query in the question, taking MAX (any row) against MIN (any row). [The Scrum Meister's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024979/oracle-sql-help-using-case-in-a-select-statement/5025002#5025002) fixes the OP's logic as well, to correctly cater for gaps between jobs.

---

This should be all you need. Having the student_schools table JOINed seems to add no value, unless there are cases where position_rd records exist without a `student_schools` record.

```
CREATE TABLE student_totalexp2 nologging compress AS
SELECT b.member_sk, 
    NVL(MAX(TO_DATE(b.end_date,'yyyymm')), SYSDATE)
      - MIN(TO_DATE(b.start_date,'yyyymm')) as days_experience
FROM rdorwart.position_rd b
GROUP BY b.member_sk
HAVING NVL(MAX(TO_DATE(b.end_date,'yyyymm')), SYSDATE)
         - MIN(TO_DATE(b.start_date,'yyyymm')) < 730
```

- The NVL takes care of replacing a non-existent end_date with SYSDATE

If you do need to validate `student_schools` - just add an INNER JOIN to it. Nowhere else is it needed.

Comment: This will return incorrect results if there are days in between job rows.

Comment: @richard-aka-cyberkiwi If a user has 2 rows: 1) 1/1/2011 to 2/1/2011 and 2) 2/10/2011 to 2/20/2011. Your query will return `51` days experience. instead of `41`. That is why a `SUM()` on the individual rows is needed (see my answer). And i think just "cyberwiki" is better

Comment: @The SM - the MAX and MIN are taken independently. so it will take 2/20 against 1/1.

Comment: @richard-aka-cyberkiwi Ya which will output `51`. The OP wants (look in the comments to my answer) the output to be `41`.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use guiven name of the field directly in where clause. You need to repeat the logic in where clause

```
select /*+parallel(a,4)*/ distinct a.member_sk,  
CASE WHEN b.end_date is null 
THEN sysdate - min(to_date(b.start_date,'yyyymm'))  
ELSE (max(to_date(b.end_date,'yyyymm')) - min(to_date(b.start_date,'yyyymm'))) 
END as days_experience       
from student_schools a INNER JOIN rdorwart.position_rd b        
ON a.member_sk = b.member_sk          
where (CASE WHEN b.end_date is null 
       THEN sysdate - min(to_date(b.start_date,'yyyymm'))  
       ELSE (max(to_date(b.end_date,'yyyymm')) - min(to_date(b.start_date,'yyyymm'))) 
       END) < 730          
group by a.member_sk;     
select count(*) from student_experience;
```

Answer (score 0):

For short and more readable code, use an outer SELECT:

```
CREATE TABLE student_totalexp2 nologging compress AS
SELECT member_sk, days_experience FROM (
    SELECT a.member_sk
         , SUM(CASE WHEN b.end_date IS NULL 
               THEN sysdate ELSE to_date(b.end_date,'yyyymm') END
               - to_date(b.start_date,'yyyymm')) AS days_experience
    FROM student_schools a
    INNER JOIN rdorwart.position_rd b ON a.member_sk = b.member_sk
    GROUP BY a.member_sk)
WHERE days_experience < 730;


SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM student_experience;
```